# Confusion about the index of a sequence of simple functions, that approximates a measb. function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, simple-functions

It is known that a measurable function $f$ can always be approximated by a sequence of simple functions $f_n\uparrow f$ (pointwise). We can represent a simple function as
$g=\sum_{i=1}^mx_i\bf{1}_{A_j}$ where $\bf{1}_{A_j}$ the indicator function. My question: if we have $g_n\uparrow f$ do we mean that $n=m$ so that we have,$f=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i\bf{1}_{A_j}$? The latter is not a simple function annymore since it doesn't take finite values. Or doesn't it have to be the case that $m=n$?

Comment: $n$ is the index of $g_n$ as an item in the sequence $g_1,g_2,\dots$. So there is no connection whatsoever between $n$ and the $m$ in summation expression.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. Take a strictely increasing function on $\mathbb R$. Then, $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=-n^2}^{n^2}f(k/n)\boldsymbol 1_{[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]}(x),$$
but obviously, $f$ won't be of this form.